# How to Create the Edit View that gets CheckBoxes from a List stored in DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Need to create the edit View with selected Checkboxes from createView

```
public class CustomerTypeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Please select the Type")]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerView when i should load a list of CustomerTypeViewModel

```
public List<CustomerTypeViewModel> SelectedCustomerTypes { get; set; }
private List<CustomerTypeViewModel> selectionList = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>();
public CustomerViewModel()
{
    SelectedCustomerTypes = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>();
}

public void SetCustomerTypeViewModel(IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewModel> selected, IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewModel> all)
{
    SelectedCustomerTypes.Clear();
    foreach (var item in all)
    {
        SelectedCustomerTypes.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        SelectedCustomerTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Description == item.Description).Selected = true;
    }
}

public List<CustomerTypeViewModel> GetTipi()
{
    return selectionList;
}
```

In controller i should call a method that get customertypes from manager

```
public CustomerTypeViewModel GetCustomerType(int? customerId)
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerType where Id = @Id";
    return context.GetObject<CustomerTypeViewModel>(query, new { Id = customerId });
}
```

Now in the Edit at the Controller

```
[AuthorizeRoles(RoleNames.CanEditCustomer)]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int? customerId)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var customer = customerManager.Get(customerId);
    var vm = new CustomerViewModel();
    vm.SetCustomerTypeViewModel(new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>(), customerTypeManager.GetAll());
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

I was told to create a method in manager GetCustomerType(customerId)
<-- this is the id from db table where checkboxes are saved and this method load a list of CustomerTypeViewModel

Now Edit View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedCustomerTypes.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Label(Model.SelectedCustomerTypes[i].Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerTypes[i].Selected, new { @checked = "checked" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerTypes[i].Id, new { data_val = false })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerTypes[i].Description, new { data_val = false })
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Does this code: 'var query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerType where Id = @Id";  '  works in your controller?

Comment: Yes it gets the Id of created checkboxes. CustomerType has Id, Description and a boolean. when boolean is true the value is sent to a new table CustomerCheckedType ..

Comment: That code is doing nothing. You think that you are getting the ID but if you debug it you will see that you are not

Comment: at least concatenate the string like this: var query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerType where Id ==" + @Id; And still it will give an error cause the compiler does not know what is the @Id

Comment: any idea how should i fix it? the create for checkboxes works good. but can't manage to do the edit for the edit view

Comment: the edit needs 2 views: one to Get the info from the db to display in the page and another to Post the information in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the GetCustomerType method in your controller. Try this:

```
public IActionResult GetCostumerType(int? id)
{

   if (id == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

   var test = from custom in _yourContext.CustomerType                   
              .Where(p => p.CustomerType.Id == customerId)
              select custom;
              //change _yourContext with your context variable                  

   if (test == null)
   {
     return NotFound();
   }

   return View(test);
}
```

This way you are getting the custom types associated with the id passed in the method.

Comment: i add this in CustomerController?

Comment: This will allow you to get the CustomerType associated with the id that you are passing

Comment: change your GetCustomerType method with this